# How can i get the name of property and value from object and pass this name and value to a list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to get the property name and the value from object and pass them to the list.
i dont want to pass one by one property and value to the list like commented in my code. want to use loop and add name and value dynamically

```
public class ParametersList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }
}
 public class BookVM
{
    
  public string AuthorName{ get; set; }
   
    public string CoverUrl { get; set; }

    public int AuthorIds { get; set; }

}

public List<Book> Addgetallbooks(BookVM BookVM)
    {
        List<ParametersList> obj = new List<ParametersList>();
       
        //List<ParametersList> obj = new List<ParametersList>
        //{
        //    new ParametersList{Name=nameof(BookVM.AuthorIds),Value=BookVM.AuthorIds},
        //    new ParametersList{Name=nameof(BookVM.AuthorName),Value=BookVM.AuthorName},
        //    new ParametersList{Name=nameof(BookVM.CoverUrl),Value=BookVM.CoverUrl}
        //};
        var getdata = _opr.GetBooks1(obj);
        return getdata;
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO, what you are looking for is called Reflection, but i have to warn you it is not very fast. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use reflection, but not sure if you should do it :)

```
[TestMethod]
public void Foo()
{
    var book = new BookVM() { AuthorIds = 1, AuthorName = "some name", CoverUrl = "some cover url" };
    var result = GetParameters(book);
    result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[]
    {
        new ParametersList { Name = nameof(BookVM.AuthorIds), Value = 1 },
        new ParametersList() { Name = nameof(BookVM.AuthorName), Value = "some name" },
        new ParametersList { Name = nameof(BookVM.CoverUrl), Value = "some cover url" }
    });
}

private static List<ParametersList> GetParameters(BookVM book)
{
    return typeof(BookVM).GetProperties().Select(p => new ParametersList
    {
        Name = p.Name, Value = p.GetValue(book)
    }).ToList();
}
```